# Convert bar bullet chart into column chart

Tags: javascript, ajax, charts, highcharts

Here is example of highchart bullet chart http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/LdHYt/1/
How can we convert this into a column bullet chart?

```
//-------------------------------------------------------
Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.line = function(x, y, width, height) {
    return ['M',x ,y + width / 2,'L',x+height,y + width / 2];
};
//-------------------------------------------------------
Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart:{
        type:'bar',
        margin:[5,15,10,100],
    },
    credits:{enabled:false},
    exporting:{enabled:false},
    legend:{enabled:false},
    title:{text:''},
    xAxis:{
        tickLength:0,
        lineColor:'#999',
        lineWidth:1,
        labels:{style:{fontWeight:'bold'}}        
    },
    yAxis:{
        min:0,
        minPadding:0,
        maxPadding:0,
        tickColor:'#ccc',
        tickWidth:1,
        tickLength:3,
        gridLineWidth:0,
        endOnTick:true,
        title:{text: ''},
        labels:{
            y:10,
            style:{
                fontSize:'8px'
            },
            formatter:function(){
                if (this.isLast){
                    return this.value + ' %';
                }
                else{
                    return this.value;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip:{
        enabled:true,
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, .85)',
        borderWidth:0,
        shadow:true,
        style:{fontSize:'10px',padding:2},
        formatter:function() {
           return this.series.name + ": <strong>" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2) + "</strong>";
        }
    },
    plotOptions:{
        bar:{
            color:'#000',
            shadow:false,
            borderWidth:0,
        },
        scatter:{
            marker:{
                symbol:'line',
                lineWidth:3,
                radius:8,
                lineColor:'#000'
            }
        }
    }
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{renderTo:'container1'},
    xAxis:{categories:['Title 1']},
    yAxis:{
        max:100,
        labels:{y:10,style:{fontSize:'8px'}},    
        plotBands:[{from:0,to:70,color: 'rgba(103,103,103,.35)'},
                   {from:70,to:85,color: 'rgba(153,153,153,.35)'},
                   {from:85,to:100,color: 'rgba(204,204,204,.35)'}]
    },
    series:[{name:'Measure',pointWidth:10,data:[80]},
            {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[90],}]
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{renderTo:'container2'},
    xAxis:{categories:['Title 2']},
    yAxis:{
        max:100,
        labels:{y:10,style:{fontSize:'8px'}},   
        plotBands:[{from:0,to:75,color: 'rgba(103,103,103,.35)'},
                   {from:75,to:90,color: 'rgba(153,153,153,.35)'},
                   {from:90,to:100,color: 'rgba(204,204,204,.35)'}]
    },
    series:[{name:'Measure',pointWidth:10,data:[92]},
            {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[95],}]
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{renderTo:'container3'},
    xAxis:{categories:['Title 3']},
    yAxis:{
        max:100,
        labels:{y:10,style:{fontSize:'8px'}},   
        plotBands:[{from:0,to:50,color: 'rgba(103,103,103,.35)'},
                   {from:50,to:75,color: 'rgba(153,153,153,.35)'},
                   {from:75,to:100,color: 'rgba(204,204,204,.35)'}]
    },
    series:[{name:'Measure',pointWidth:10,data:[64]},
            {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[75],}]
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart4 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{renderTo:'container4'},
    xAxis:{categories:['Title 4']},
    yAxis:{
        max:1000,
        labels:{y:10,style:{fontSize:'8px'},formatter:function(){return this.value;}},   
        plotBands:[{from:0,to:600,color: 'rgba(103,103,103,.35)'},
                   {from:600,to:800,color: 'rgba(153,153,153,.35)'},
                   {from:800,to:1000,color: 'rgba(204,204,204,.35)'}]
    },
    series:[{name:'Measure',pointWidth:10,data:[970]},
            {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[850],}]
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart5 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart:{renderTo:'container5'},
    xAxis:{categories:['Title 5']},
    yAxis:{
        max:500,tickInterval:100,
        labels:{y:10,style:{fontSize:'8px'},formatter:function(){return this.value;}},   
        plotBands:[{from:0,to:300,color: 'rgba(103,103,103,.35)'},
                   {from:300,to:400,color: 'rgba(153,153,153,.35)'},
                   {from:400,to:500,color: 'rgba(204,204,204,.35)'}]
    },
    series:[{name:'Measure',pointWidth:10,data:[475]},
            {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[450],}]
});
//-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LdHYt/390/ tada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what you're looking for? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LdHYt/390/)

```js
//-------------------------------------------------------
Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.line = function(x, y, width, height) {
  return ['M', x, y + width / 2, 'L', x + height, y + width / 2];
};
//-------------------------------------------------------
Highcharts.setOptions({
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    inverted: false,
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    tickLength: 0,
    lineColor: '#999',
    lineWidth: 1,
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minPadding: 0,
    maxPadding: 0,
    tickColor: '#ccc',
    tickWidth: 1,
    tickLength: 3,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    endOnTick: true,
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    labels: {
      y: 10,
      style: {
        fontSize: '8px'
      },
      formatter: function() {
        if (this.isLast) {
          return this.value + ' %';
        } else {
          return this.value;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .85)',
    borderWidth: 0,
    shadow: true,
    style: {
      fontSize: '10px',
      padding: 2
    },
    formatter: function() {
      return this.series.name + ": <strong>" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + "</strong>";
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      color: '#000',
      shadow: false,
      borderWidth: 0,
    },
    scatter: {
      marker: {
        symbol: 'line',
        lineWidth: 3,
        radius: 8,
        lineColor: '#000'
      }
    }
  }
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container1'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Title 1']
  },
  yAxis: {
    max: 100,
    labels: {
      y: 10,
      style: {
        fontSize: '8px'
      }
    },
    plotBands: [{
      from: 0,
      to: 70,
      color: 'rgba(103,103,103,.35)'
    }, {
      from: 70,
      to: 85,
      color: 'rgba(153,153,153,.35)'
    }, {
      from: 85,
      to: 100,
      color: 'rgba(204,204,204,.35)'
    }]
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Measure',
    pointWidth: 10,
    data: [80]
  }, {
    name: 'Target',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [90],
  }]
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container2'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Title 2']
  },
  yAxis: {
    max: 100,
    labels: {
      y: 10,
      style: {
        fontSize: '8px'
      }
    },
    plotBands: [{
      from: 0,
      to: 75,
      color: 'rgba(103,103,103,.35)'
    }, {
      from: 75,
      to: 90,
      color: 'rgba(153,153,153,.35)'
    }, {
      from: 90,
      to: 100,
      color: 'rgba(204,204,204,.35)'
    }]
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Measure',
    pointWidth: 10,
    data: [92]
  }, {
    name: 'Target',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [95],
  }]
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container3'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Title 3']
  },
  yAxis: {
    max: 100,
    labels: {
      y: 10,
      style: {
        fontSize: '8px'
      }
    },
    plotBands: [{
      from: 0,
      to: 50,
      color: 'rgba(103,103,103,.35)'
    }, {
      from: 50,
      to: 75,
      color: 'rgba(153,153,153,.35)'
    }, {
      from: 75,
      to: 100,
      color: 'rgba(204,204,204,.35)'
    }]
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Measure',
    pointWidth: 10,
    data: [64]
  }, {
    name: 'Target',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [75],
  }]
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart4 = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container4'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Title 4']
  },
  yAxis: {
    max: 1000,
    labels: {
      y: 10,
      style: {
        fontSize: '8px'
      },
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value;
      }
    },
    plotBands: [{
      from: 0,
      to: 600,
      color: 'rgba(103,103,103,.35)'
    }, {
      from: 600,
      to: 800,
      color: 'rgba(153,153,153,.35)'
    }, {
      from: 800,
      to: 1000,
      color: 'rgba(204,204,204,.35)'
    }]
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Measure',
    pointWidth: 10,
    data: [970]
  }, {
    name: 'Target',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [850],
  }]
});

//-------------------------------------------------------
var chart5 = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container5'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Title 5']
  },
  yAxis: {
    max: 500,
    tickInterval: 100,
    labels: {
      y: 10,
      style: {
        fontSize: '8px'
      },
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value;
      }
    },
    plotBands: [{
      from: 0,
      to: 300,
      color: 'rgba(103,103,103,.35)'
    }, {
      from: 300,
      to: 400,
      color: 'rgba(153,153,153,.35)'
    }, {
      from: 400,
      to: 500,
      color: 'rgba(204,204,204,.35)'
    }]
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Measure',
    pointWidth: 10,
    data: [475]
  }, {
    name: 'Target',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [450],
  }]
});
//-------------------------------------------------------
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: .7em;
}
p {
  margin: .5em 1em;
}
#container1,
#container2,
#container3,
#container4,
#container5 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container1" style="height:auto;width:100px;"></div>
<div id="container2" style="height:auto;width:100px;"></div>
<div id="container3" style="height:auto;width:100px;"></div>
<div id="container4" style="height:auto;width:100px;"></div>
<div id="container5" style="height:auto;width:100px;"></div>
```